# how to use the sep parameter in the print function correctly

Tags: python, function, printing, parameters, separator

I have been experimenting with building dictionaries in python. Please consider the following code:

```
brad_pitt = {
'name': ['brad pitt'],
'profession': ['actor'],
'birthday': ['18.12.1963'],
'sign': ['sagittarius'],
'birthplace': ['shawnee / oklahoma (usa)'],
'nationality': ['usa'],
'height': ['182 cm'],
'weight': ['76 kg'], 
'marital status': ['married'],
'sex': ['male'],
'ex-partner': ['gwyneth paltrow', 'jennifer aniston', 'angelina jolie'],
'eye color': ['blue'],
}

julia_roberts = {
'name': ['julia roberts'],
'profession': ['actor'],
'birthday': ['28.10.1967'],
'sign': ['scorpion'],
'birthplace': ['atlanta / georgia (usa)'],
'nationality': ['usa'],
'height': ['174 cm'],
'weight': ['57 kg'], 
'marital status': ['married'],
'sex': ['female'],
'ex-partner': ['liam neeson'],
'eye color': ['brown'],
}

george_clooney = {
'name': ['george clooney'],
'profession': ['actor'],
'birthday': ['06.05.1961'],
'sign': ['taurus'],
'birthplace': ['lexington / kentucky (usa)'],
'nationality': ['usa'],
'height': ['180 cm'],
'weight': ['74 kg'], 
'marital status': ['married'],
'sex': ['male'],
'ex-partner': ['naomi campbell', 'elle macpherson', 'renée zellweger', 'amal clooney'],
'eye color': ['brown'],
}

people = [brad_pitt, julia_roberts, george_clooney]

for person in people:
    for key, value in person.items():
        if len(value) > 1:
            print(f"{key.title()}: ", end="")
            for partner in value:
                print(f"{partner}".title(), sep=',', end="")
            print()
        else:
            print(f"{key.title()}: {value[0].title()}")
    print()
```

I expected the ex-partners to be separated by a comma...

I don't see the mistake in my print statement.

I used the optional parameter sep to separate the different entries from the list.

Comment: Whats the print output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sep` is for passing multiple arguments to `print`. Rather set `end=","`.

Better yet, just do this:

```
for key, value in person.items():
    print(f"{key.title()}: {','.join(v.title() for v in value)}")
```

Comment: This looks like an elegant solution to me @Alex Hall, thanks. I just added a space character after the comma. What is the name of the concept you use here? Somehow it looks similar to a list comprehension, but I think you wouldn't call it like that, would you?

Comment: I reviewed your suggestion and would call the concept: concatenate a list into a string using a separator. v.title() for v in value returns a list. Then concatenate the v's in value separating them with ', ' and you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

`sep` is used when you pass a list of strings to be separated, you seem to be passing the strings one by one in a `for` loop. I'd either remove the `for` loop and just print `value`, or change it to `end=','`

e.g.

```py
for partner in value:
    print(f"{partner}".title(), end=", ")
```

or

```py
print(f"{value}".title(), sep=', ' , end="")
```